# Does a US citizen need a UK visa for an internship?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, working-visas

I have accepted a 3-month internship within the UK. I am signing a 1 year lease but am confused on how to get a visa. Do I need to get one before leaving the US? If so, what kind? The company might offer me a job, but hasn't yet, so I'm not sponsored.

Comment: Please describe the internship in exact detail

Comment: @DJClayworth Not that simple. Certain work may be performed visa-free, but only for 1 or 3 months rather than 6

Comment: @DJClayworth https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/work/six_months_or_less

Comment: Can you  cancel or sublet the 1 year lease after 3 months? If not, it may not be a good idea.

Comment: Internships are sponsored activities just like work permits are, have you discussed this with your sponsor's Authorising Officer?  I smell a bounce...

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan a 1 year lease to a visitor is illegal, please read https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/landlords-immigration-right-to-rent-checks

Comment: @GayotFow I was not thinking about right-to-rent issues but just whether there will be any problem if the OP has to leave after 3 months.

Comment: You need a visa to work in the UK, you even need a visa to 'volunteer' so made need one even if you're not getting paid

Answer (score 3):

The list of activities you are allowed to do on a Standard Visitor visa (or a visa free passport, such as in the case of US citizens) is available [in detail](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules#visitors-appendix-3-permitted-activities-for-all-visitors-except-transit-visitors) on the Gov.UK website. The only reasonably fitting activity would be:

> 23 Employees of an overseas company or organisation may receive training from a UK based company or organisation in work practices and techniques which are required for the visitor’s employment overseas and not available in their home country.

However assuming you are not an employee of the US branch of the UK company, you are not allowed to participate in an internship as a regular visitor. In this case you should apply for a work visa. The exact type of the work visa must be clarified with your employer, e.g. you might be eligible for a [Tier 5 (Temporary Worker - Government Authorised Exchange) visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-5-government-authorised-exchange).

You might be tempted to ignore the advice above and attempt to enter visa-free, lying about the true goals of your visit to the immigration officer. However be aware that such an approach is highly unrecommended and may end up with you 
banned from visiting the UK for many years to come.

Answer (score 0):

Using [the Gov.UK portal](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/work/six_months_or_less), and with my legal head on, I suggest you read **If you want to work in the UK** in that link. Your internship would seem to be analogous to "work experience", in that its not permanent, is not brief and is likely to be unpaid so I suggest your course of action is to do what it says there *Apply for a temporary worker visa if you want to work in the UK for a short time*

Comment: Your answer would be better if you directly linked the mentioned page in your answer, so people don't have to look for it. Also consider quoting the relevant text directly in your answer, so people don't have to visit the site. It also might become dead after a certain time and then your answer would become useless.

Comment: its linked above, and I name the author. I didn't see the point in repeating the link. However since you mention the _reason_ for quoting the text, I will consider doing so in future.